# How to do an subtraction based in multiple columns - R

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a huge database monthly actualizated, here i'll try to create an exemple

| Year | Month | UF | Seg | Fai | Value | LinProd | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | B | 1 | Prod1 | Comp.1 |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | B | 7 | Prod1 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | C | 5 | Prod2 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | B | 2 | Prod1 | Comp.2 |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Location | A | 4 | Prod2 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | A | 8 | Prod4 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | B | 16 | Prod4 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | F | 2 | Prod4 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | A | 3 | Prod4 | Comp.1 |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | B | 8 | Prod4 | Comp.2 |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | F | 1 | Prod4 | Comp.2 |

This database is exported from an excel, what I need to do is basically, a subtraction, Market-(Comp.1+Comp2). Respecting all the columns. The output I need is something like:

| Year | Month | UF | Seg | Fai | Value | LinProd | Brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | B | 4 | Prod1 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | SP | Construction | C | 5 | Prod2 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Location | A | 4 | Prod2 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | A | 5 | Prod4 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | B | 8 | Prod4 | Market |
| 2021 | Nov | MG | Mineration | F | 1 | Prod4 | Market |

Where there is no subtraction, I just to be printed as it was before, as you can see in the line 5 from the fist table and in the line 3 from the second, there was no product from Comp.1 and Comp.2, so nothing happened to it

I tried this code:

```
t<-as.data.frame(read_xlsx("C:/Users/lucas/Documents/Base.xlsx"))

c=as.data.frame(filter(t,Brand=="Comp.1"))
c$Value=c$Value*-1

ti=as.data.frame(filter(t,Brand=="Market"))

n=as.data.frame(filter(t,Brand=="Comp.2"))
n$Value=n$Value*-1

mar=rbind(ti,c,n)
ag=aggregate(mar$Value,by=list(mar$Brand,mar$Month,mar$UF, mar$Seg,mar$Fai,mar$LinProd),FUN = sum)

write_xlsx(ag,"C:/Users/lucas/Documents/Test.xlsx" )
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative `dplyr` solution, plus base:

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Year, Month, UF, Seg, Fai) %>%
  mutate(Value = Value - sum(Value[ Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2") ])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#    Year Month UF    Seg          Fai   Value LinProd Brand 
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr> <int> <chr>   <chr> 
# 1  2021 Nov   SP    Construction B         4 Prod1   Market
# 2  2021 Nov   SP    Construction C         5 Prod2   Market
# 3  2021 Nov   MG    Location     A         4 Prod2   Market
# 4  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   A         5 Prod4   Market
# 5  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   B         8 Prod4   Market
# 6  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   F         1 Prod4   Market
```

### base R

```r
dat$Value <- 
  ave(dat$Value * ifelse(dat$Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2"), -1, 1), dat[,c("Year", "Month", "UF", "Seg", "Fai")],
      FUN = function(z) z + sum(z[z < 0]))
dat[!dat$Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2"),]
#   Year Month UF          Seg Fai Value LinProd  Brand Value2
# 2 2021   Nov SP Construction   B     4   Prod1 Market      4
# 3 2021   Nov SP Construction   C     5   Prod2 Market      5
# 5 2021   Nov MG     Location   A     4   Prod2 Market      4
# 6 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   A     5   Prod4 Market      5
# 7 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   B     8   Prod4 Market      8
# 8 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   F     1   Prod4 Market      1
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
# should instead use `setDT(dat)` if going this route
as.data.table(dat
  )[, Value2 := Value - sum(Value[Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2")]), by = .(Year, Month, UF, Seg, Fai)
    ][ !Brand %in% c("Comp.1", "Comp.2") ]
#    Year Month UF          Seg Fai Value LinProd  Brand Value2
# 1: 2021   Nov SP Construction   B     7   Prod1 Market      4
# 2: 2021   Nov SP Construction   C     5   Prod2 Market      5
# 3: 2021   Nov MG     Location   A     4   Prod2 Market      4
# 4: 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   A     8   Prod4 Market      5
# 5: 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   B    16   Prod4 Market      8
# 6: 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   F     2   Prod4 Market      1
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), Month = c("Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov"), UF = c("SP", "SP", "SP", "SP", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG"), Seg = c("Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Location", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration"), Fai = c("B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F"), Value = c(1L,  7L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L), LinProd = c("Prod1", "Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4"), Brand = c("Comp.1", "Market", "Market", "Comp.2", "Market", "Market", "Market", "Market", "Comp.1", "Comp.2", "Comp.2"), Value2 = c(-4, 4, 5, -5, 4, 5, 8, 1, -6, -16, -2)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Value2 = ifelse(Brand == "Comp.1" | Brand == "Comp.2", Value*-1, Value)) %>%
  group_by(Year, Month, UF, Seg, Fai, LinProd) %>%
  summarize(Value_new = sum(Value2)) %>%
  arrange(Seg, LinProd)

# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   Year, Month, UF, Seg, Fai [6]
   Year Month UF    Seg          Fai   LinProd Value_new
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
1  2021 Nov   SP    Construction B     Prod1           4
2  2021 Nov   SP    Construction C     Prod2           5
3  2021 Nov   MG    Location     A     Prod2           4
4  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   A     Prod4           5
5  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   B     Prod4           8
6  2021 Nov   MG    Mineration   F     Prod4           1
```

Or base R:

```
df$Value2 <- ifelse(df$Brand == "Comp.1" | df$Brand == "Comp.2", df$Value*-1, df$Value)
df_sum <- aggregate(Value2 ~ Year + Month + UF + Seg + Fai + LinProd, data = df, FUN = sum)
df_sum[order(df_sum$Seg, df_sum$LinProd),]

  Year Month UF          Seg Fai LinProd Value2
1 2021   Nov SP Construction   B   Prod1      4
3 2021   Nov SP Construction   C   Prod2      5
2 2021   Nov MG     Location   A   Prod2      4
4 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   A   Prod4      5
5 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   B   Prod4      8
6 2021   Nov MG   Mineration   F   Prod4      1
```

Data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), Month = c("Nov", "Nov", "Nov", 
"Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov"), UF = c("SP", 
"SP", "SP", "SP", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG", "MG"), 
    Seg = c("Construction", "Construction", "Construction", "Construction", 
    "Location", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration", "Mineration", 
    "Mineration", "Mineration"), Fai = c("B", "B", "C", "B", 
    "A", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F"), Value = c(1L, 7L, 5L, 
    2L, 4L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 1L), LinProd = c("Prod1", "Prod1", 
    "Prod2", "Prod1", "Prod2", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4", "Prod4", 
    "Prod4", "Prod4"), Brand = c("Comp.1", "Market", "Market", 
    "Comp.2", "Market", "Market", "Market", "Market", "Comp.1", 
    "Comp.2", "Comp.2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```